# Multiple variables using same value for different IDs

Tags: jquery

I'm using the window location and the DIV ID of `IncludeCMSContent1, IncludeCMSContent2, IncludeCMSContent3` on a single page application. When those conditions are met the external content is injected at the ID.

However, I'm finding that only 1 of the 3 variables is firing, the first one actually, because if `IncludeCMSContent3` is present on the page, this ID won't fire because `IncludeCMSContent1` is taking precedence.

How can I solve for this? The page is always the same, so the value is always the same, but the ID of `IncludeCMSContent1/2/3` will swap on the same page.

```
var TCEApplicationNoWaiver = "TCEApplication.aspx"
var TCEApplicationWaiver = "TCEApplication.aspx"
var TCEApplicationNotEligible = "TCEApplication.aspx"

if (window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf(TCEApplicationNoWaiver.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
            $("#IncludeCMSContent1").load("http://www.example.com/tce-application-noWaiver.htm #externalContent");
}
else if (window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf(TCEApplicationWaiver.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
            $("#IncludeCMSContent2").load("http://www.example.com/tce-application-Waiver.htm #externalContent");
}
else if (window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf(TCEApplicationNotEligible.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
            $("#IncludeCMSContent3").load("http://www.example.com/not-eligible.htm #externalContent");
}
```

Comment: remove the else? Your statement will only trigger one of those cases currently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `else` statement so all the conditions will be triggered:

```
if (window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf(TCEApplicationNoWaiver.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
    $("#IncludeCMSContent1").load("http://www.example.com/tce-application-noWaiver.htm #externalContent");
}

if (window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf(TCEApplicationWaiver.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
    $("#IncludeCMSContent2").load("http://www.example.com/tce-application-Waiver.htm #externalContent");
}

if (window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf(TCEApplicationNotEligible.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
    $("#IncludeCMSContent3").load("http://www.example.com/not-eligible.htm #externalContent");
}
```

Hope this helps.